# How do I remove the empty row in an ASP.NET GridView when EmptyDataTemplate is being used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a ASP.NET GridView which I want to display a series of textBoxs in when the gridView is empty so the user can add more data. Functionally it all works but when it renders it appears to have an extra row between the headers and my row of textBoxs.

```html
 <table class="grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridViewReferences" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
   <th align="left" scope="col" style="width:50px;">Id</th><th align="left" scope="col">Reference</th><th align="left" scope="col" style="width:400px;">Source</th><th align="left" scope="col" style="width:50px;">Edit</th><th align="left" scope="col" style="width:50px;">Delete</th>
  </tr><tr>
   <td colspan="5">
                <tr style="background-color: #E8ECED;">
                    <td>
                        <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;">0</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridViewReferences$ctl02$textBoxReference" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridViewReferences_textBoxReference" class="ZenStyle" style="width:100%;" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridViewReferences$ctl02$textBoxSource" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridViewReferences_textBoxSource" class="ZenStyle" style="width:400px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridViewReferences_LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridViewReferences$ctl02$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;">Insert</a>
                        <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridViewReferences_ValidationSummary1" style="display:none;">

   </div>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

When I examine the rendered HTML there is indeed an extra row but I can't workout how to either add my textBoxs to it or remove it. My .aspx code for the grid...I've not included the code behind or the styling as I don't think it's relevant.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gridViewReferences" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="grid" EnableViewState="false"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridAltRow" RowStyle-CssClass="gridRow" ShowFooter="True"
        EditRowStyle-CssClass="gridEditRow" FooterStyle-CssClass="gridFooterRow" OnRowCancelingEdit="gridViewReferences_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowCommand="gridViewReferences_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gridViewReferences_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="gridViewReferences_RowDeleting"
        OnRowEditing="gridViewReferences_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gridViewReferences_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="Id" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
        <Columns>
            <%--ID column ( which also acts as the key )--%>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <HeaderStyle Width="50" />
                <ItemStyle Width="50" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Id")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

             <%--Reference column--%>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reference" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" ID="textBoxReference" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Reference") %>' CssClass="ZenStyle"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" ID="textBoxReference" runat="server" CssClass="ZenStyle"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Reference") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <%--Source column--%>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Source" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <HeaderStyle Width="400" />
                <ItemStyle Width="400" />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" ID="textBoxSource" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Source") %>' CssClass="ZenStyle"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Width="100%" ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Source")%>' CssClass="ZenStyle" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" ID="textBoxSource" runat="server" CssClass="ZenStyle" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <%--Edit / Update  column--%>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <HeaderStyle Width="50" />
                <ItemStyle Width="50" />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Update2"
                        Text="Update" ValidationGroup="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                        Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" Text="Insert"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsInsert" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false"
                        ValidationGroup="Insert" Enabled="true" HeaderText="Validation..." />
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                        Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <%--Delete column--%>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <HeaderStyle Width="50" />
                <ItemStyle Width="50" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" CssClass="myButton"
                        Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete?')"></asp:Button>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <tr style="background-color: #E8ECED;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Width="50px" runat="server">0</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" ID="textBoxReference" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Reference") %>' CssClass="ZenStyle"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="400px" ID="textBoxSource" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Source") %>' CssClass="ZenStyle"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton Width="50px" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" Text="Insert"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup="Insert" Enabled="true" HeaderText="Validation..." />
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around with this

```
<EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyDataClass" />
<EmptyDataTemplate>
 ...
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

And in your css :

```
.EmptyDataVacancyClass {
    display: none;
}
```